# Como mostrar campos do Json com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

Eu tenho o seguinte Json numa variável PHP:

```
[
   {"pergunta[0]":"Quantos anos?"},
   {"pergunta[1]":"Qual sua altura?"},
   {"resposta[0]":"12"},
   {"resposta[1]":"1.65"}
]
```

e meu objetivo é mostrar ele da seguinte forma:

Quantos anos? 12.

Qual sua altura? 1.65.

Eu tentei dessa forma:

```
$obj = json_decode([{"pergunta[0]":"Quantos anos?"},{"pergunta[1]":"Qual sua altura?"},{"resposta[0]":"12"},{"resposta[1]":"1.65"}]);
echo $obj['pergunta'];
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Já experimentou printar `$obj` com `var_dump()` ou  `var_export` para entender que estrutura ele tem? [Veja só](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/MammothBustlingRegression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$jsonVar = json_decode('{"p0":"Quantos anos?","p1":"Qual sua altura?","r0":"12","r1":"1.65"}');

function mostrar($jsonVar)
{

    foreach ($jsonVar as $key => $value) {

        $pergunta = "none";
        $index = "0";

            if( substr($key, 0, 1) == 'p' )
            {
                $pergunta = $value;
                $index = substr($key, 1, strlen($key) );

                echo  $pergunta . " numero da pergunta:" . $index . " -> ";

                foreach ($jsonVar as $key => $value) {

                    if( $key == 'r'.$index )
                    {
                        echo "Valor da pergunta " .$index. ": " .$value. "
";
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

    mostrar($jsonVar);
```

Resultado:

```
Quantos anos? numero da pergunta:0 -> Valor da pergunta 0: 12
Qual sua altura? numero da pergunta:1 -> Valor da pergunta 1: 1.65
```

Espero ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Seu json precisa estar serializado (ser uma string) para fazer o json_decode. Por exemplo:

```
$obj = json_decode('[{"pergunta1":"Quantos anos?"},{"pergunta2":"Qual sua altura?"}]');

echo $obj[0]->pergunta1;
```